# Fetching Nil Items with Core Data causing error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently trying to use Core Data to fetch and add items to my UITableView. The fetching and adding item works fine. However, the problem is when the data has nothing, my fetch results is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", which makes sense because I have nothing in the database. But instead of crashing, I want to catch the error and produce a UIAlert error message instead of crashing. But my current code does not seem to work.

```
func fetch() {
        let itemsFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Items")

        do {
            let fetchedItem = try moc.fetch(itemsFetch) as! [Items]
            self.itemsName.append(fetchedItem.first!.name!)
            self.itemDate.append(fetchedItem.first!.date!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            //print(fetchedItem.first!.name!)
            //print(fetchedItem.first!.date!)
        } catch {
            //I thought this statement would catch the error, but it
            // is not doing that 
            print("Hello")
            fatalError("Bad things happened \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Update - I have updated the code to check for nil, however, I am getting: `Initialiser for conditional binding must have optional type not NSFetchRequest`. Not sure how to solve.

```
func fetch() {
        if let itemsFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Items") {

            do{
                let fetchedItem = try moc.fetch(itemsFetch) as! [Items]
                self.itemsName.append(fetchedItem.first!.name!)
                self.itemDate.append(fetchedItem.first!.date!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                //print(fetchedItem.first!.name!)
                //print(fetchedItem.first!.date!)
            } catch {
                print("Hello")
                fatalError("Bad things happened \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Checked")
        }
    }
```

Comment: put this line in if condition like if  let itemsFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Items") { }

Comment: Check for `nil` before accessing, unlike java swift won't throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya when i tried that method, I am getting 2 errors, Use of unresolved identifier 'itemsFetch' and Initialiser for conditional binding must have optional type, not NSFetchRequest

Comment: if let itemsFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Items")  as NSArray try this

Comment: Gives me other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use

```
 if !(itemsFetch.isEmpty){
}
else{
print("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So i found a solution. The issue was coming from inside the do statement. Here is how to resolve it.

```
let itemsFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Items")

        do{
           let fetchedItem = try moc.fetch(itemsFetch) as! [Items]
            if fetchedItem.count == 0{
                // Since i casted it to an array of items (my entity), 
                // I can check whether there are no data by checking 
                // if the length of the array is 0
                print("Checked")
            }
            else{
                self.itemsName.append(fetchedItem.first!.name!)
                self.itemDate.append(fetchedItem.first!.date!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

                //print(fetchedItem.first!.name!)
                //print(fetchedItem.first!.date!)
        } catch {
           print("Hello")
           fatalError("Bad things happened \(error)")
        }
```